# H2 Database not found error: 90146. H2 database is not created on start

Tags: spring-boot, h2

Just created a simple spring-boot project from the spring initializer. I went to add a local h2 db for testing and am unable to login. Seems that it cannot create the test db when starting up but cannot figure out why this may be the case.

```
spring:
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    platform: h2
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect=org:
          hibernate:
            dialect:
              H2Dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

`Database "mem:testdb" not found, and IFEXISTS=true, so we cant auto-create it [90146-199] 90146/90146`

Comment: Not sure if it matters but you got a semicolon in the datasource url

Answer (score 25):

In earlier version of spring, default url will be jdbc:h2:mem:testdb and testdb was created by default. from 2.3.0 onwards, if url is not mentioned it will auto generate database name. auto generated database name can be found in the spring logs.

[image]

Comment: for me it is the twelfth message from the top (in the console). Message is as follows:    `o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:36963133-9e0a-40bf-bac6-ed118afb3a97'`   I just copied and pasted the location into the console and connected.

Comment: Great tip! I found it in the log as well.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same error and I found these to be helpful:

Adding a pre-2019 version to the pom.xml file as below:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.193</version>
</dependency>
```

This fixes the error but isn't the right way to do it. The newer version of H2 Database do not create a new database as it doesn't exist by default and are enabled to false for security purposes.

A better way would be adding making changes to url as:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;IFEXISTS=FALSE;
```

Hope it helps. I made changes in my `application.properties` file.

Comment: URL changing method worked for me. Thank you very much

Comment: How to access from h2-console?

Comment: The console works fine after change from 2.4.2 to 2.4.193 or change url to jdbc:h2:mem:testdb with 2.4.2, also work fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

just append this to your `application.properties` file.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.data.jpa.repositories.bootstrap-mode=default
```

Answer (score 4):

As Stuck said.

Simply remove the semicolon:

```
wrong:    jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;
correct:  jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem with windows. I just change spring.datasource.url in application property file to `jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/sample` and run project. after that set JDBC URL to  `jdbc:h2:file:C:/data/sample`. look like picture
[JDBC URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w21Z.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem and I changed the version of Spring Boot to 2.1.3 and it works

Answer (score 1):

**wrong:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

**This below solution worked for me**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring boot in order to use h2 DB, make sure you have dependencies on your `pom.xml` file

```xml
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
     <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
     <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Your `application.yml` makes it possible to access h2 DB by URI /h2-console preceded by server URL and to connect to DB named "testdb" with username "sa" and no password, after the application has been started on the server.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to setting about h2.

In application.properties

```html
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name = false 
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
```

when you put these codes in Application.properties you can see how it work!