# Spring boot H2 database not found & not created by Liquibase

Tags: spring, spring-boot, h2, liquibase

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot application with an embedded database (H2) and create data with liquibase on application startup, but absolutely nothing is working.

When I go to http://localhost:8080/h2-console/ and try to log into jdbc:h2:mem:testdb I get

```
Database "mem:testdb" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation (not recommended in secure environments) [90149-200] 90149/90149 (Help).
```

[image]

Here's my resources/application.properties:

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password=
    spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    
    spring.h2.console.enabled=true
    
    spring.liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/changelog-master.xml
    logging.level.liquibase = INFO
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.200</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To configure H2 database automatically with given DB properties in application.properties, `H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration` class should be fired.

It is not creating your required database **testdb**, because a dependency `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` is missing in your pom.xml, to auto configure the H2 database. Once you add that dependency, your code works well.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Once after adding this, you will observe a H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration executed in logs like below

`o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'`

Comment: Hi Dinesh, I have this dependency added, still getting the error message. Any insights?

Comment: same here. i have been searching for hours. It keeps creating a `mem` db and the tests pass but by using this mem db not the file i stated in my `application.properties`

Comment: @Khushboo Have you managed to solve the problem? I'm facing the same issue currently.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow , If you want to connect via console, Spring is unable to create a PHYSICAL file testdb.mv.db in root folder, i.e C:/USERS/testdb.mv.db. I went to C:/Users/SHEKHAR , and created a New > text file ( don't save it untill you rename it to testdb.mv.db or test.mv.db. Restart Springboot, "Test Connection" is Green and Connect , takes me to Console GUI.

Answer (score 0):

In latest versions of Spring, database name is not same as 'mem:testdb'. We have to find the name from the spring log and put it in as jdbc url.

```
2023-12-25 10:28:20.076  INFO 8340 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-12-25 10:28:20.275  INFO 8340 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-12-25 10:28:20.284  INFO 8340 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:9f64ba65-4b04-49e8-bfb3-7a647ee0a99a'
2023-12-25 10:28:20.433  INFO 8340 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
```

In this log, you can see that the name of database is 'jdbc:h2:mem:9f64ba65-4b04-49e8-bfb3-7a647ee0a99a'. Put it as JDBC URL in h2-console and connect.